# How to render only mid-simulation with particle emitter

Tags: rendering, particles

I've got a particle emitter and it takes about 300 frames to start looking good (it's also slomo with time stretching), but when I choose the frame range 300-400 in Scene settings and render, it renders the simulation from the beginning, just starting at frame 300. How do I render from mid-simulation?

Comment: just set start to -300 in particle frame range

Comment: Would be interesting to know all your settings. Although setting the start to -300 might help, if rendering somehow starts the simulation at the first frame of the render, then using -300 will only shift the problem. Did you bake the simulation or is it just calculated while rendering? Without baking, simulations tend to have unpredictable results, for example because Blender doesn't know at the start frame what the state of the particles was before that frame and how the simulation moves on. Baking before rendering is always recommended with all simulations, not only particles.

Comment: Looked like I just had to bake it.